# Skyrim keyboard control reset

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I accidentally changed the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to something else, now I can't get into the controls setting to change it back. How do I reset to the default key bindings?

Comment: What did you set ESC to? Skyrim should have swapped the original keybinding for that action over to the menu in place of ESC

Comment: More importantly, Skyrim let you rebind esc?

Comment: pushing the ESC key doesn't seem to do anything, suggesting it is , somehow, unbound. the "J" key gives me access to the system tab, which allows me to change the keyboard settings, as JonK below has suggested. Many thanks to all who attempted a solution. ;}

Answer (score 5):

When you re-bound the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key Skyrim should have *swapped* the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key with whatever key that action was originally bound to, so you should be able to use whatever key you replaced to access the System Tab.

Alternatively, providing that you haven't re-bound the Journal hotkey, you can press <kbd>J</kbd> to open the Journal and then simply click over to the System tab to change/review your keybindings.

Comment: thanks. i didn't see the system tab before. all is well now

Answer (score 2):

You can actually reset the control map (according to [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2260772) thread or [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111112074148AAd9lJF) Yahoo answer). You'll have to delete the following two files:

1. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim\ControlMap_Custom.txt`
2. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim\Data\Interface\Controls\PC\controlmap.txt`

To be sure, do not delete this while running Skyrim or Steam. I do not have Skyrim to test it, but what I can deduce from the filenames this will do what you want.